# How to get the json data from a separate js file to main js file

Tags: json, requirejs

In my project I wanted to keep the data separate from templates and main.js file. For example,

in my data.js :

```
define({
    heading: "Some Heading",
    subHeading : "Subheading is cool"
});
```

in my main.js,

```
require(['jquery', 'data'], function($, data){
       console.log("data object is :" + data);
);
```

This works and I get intended result on the console. Similarly I wanted to make an api call and get the json data so I updated my data.js as below,

```
define(function(){
    require(["http://some api url.com?apikey=apikey&callback=define"],
        function (someData) {
           return someData;     
        }
     );
});
```

but, I don't get the json data on main.js from the API call, I get "**data object is : undefined**" .

I am not sure how do I get the "someData" on the main.js file.

Any help pointing to the possible fix is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do server calls and load files via requireJS. You should be using ajax calls to do this. You can use [getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) method of jQuery.
E.g.

```
$.getJSON("http://some api url.com?apikey=apikey",function (someData) {
       //perform the calculations needed with someData here
       console.log(someData);     
});
```

Comment: Thanks Janith. Tried this method too, however I'm unable to access "someData" on main js file and still get as 'undefined' :(

Comment: Thanks for your time. I was thinking not to perform any action on data js file and simply get the json object on main js file and do the action there, for example - get template and get the json from data js and render to the html.

Comment: Having data and the template separate is the best approach. What you can do is to load the template from requirejs (text plugin) and load the data from the server using the getJSON method, and populate the template within the getJSON method.

Comment: Thanks for taking a stab on this. yes, calling the template on success it does work, but data and the operation happens in the same file. Keeping the scale of the project I am involved, I am thinking If I can keep data, template and operation in different files.

Comment: This was what I suggested :), Keep the template on a separate file, load it using requirejs, data on the server side, load by getJSON. You can have a look at a reference architecture we've created at http://boilerplatejs.org/ and you may implement something like this: https://github.com/ectechno/boilerplatejs/blob/master/src/modules/sampleModule2/employeeList/component.js We keep the view, and model seperate and use MVVM architecture

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all for taking a stab at my issue! I have been able to get this working using a plugin 'async'. Basically, I posted my issue on Google Group as well and I received a response, here is the url for more information,
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/requirejs/39rieY2ZovE

hope this helps to all.

Thanks.
radiant

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [RequireJS plugins](https://github.com/millermedeiros/requirejs-plugins).

For JSON data, you change the require to

```
require([`json!http://some api url.com?apikey=apikey&callback=define`], 
        function(someData){
          // do something
        });
```